# Weakest condition on $f\colon \Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ so that $f(\|x\|_1,\|x\|_2)$ is a norm.

Tags: linear-algebra, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\|#1\|_1}\newcommand{\morm}[1]{\|#1\|_2}\newcommand{\xorm}[1]{\|#1\|_3}$

> Let $X$ be a finite dimensional Banach space and $f\colon \Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$. What is the weakest condition on $f$ that ensures that $\xorm{x}=f\big(\norm{x},\morm{x}\big)$ is a norm on $X$ for any choice of norms $\norm{\cdot},\morm{\cdot}$ on $X$?

I found the following assumptions and wonder if it is possible to do better:

- $f(t,s)\geq 0$ with $\text{"$=$"}\iff s=t=0$.
- $f$ is positively one homogeneous, $i.e. f(\lambda(s,t))=\lambda f(s,t)$ for every $\lambda >0$.
- $f(s+t,a+b)\leq f(s,a)+f(t,b)$ for every $a,b,s,t>0$.

Somehow this reminds me the notion of sublinearity.

**EDIT** Actually I realized that if $f$ satisfies these properties, then $f$ is a norm on $\{(s,t)\in\Bbb R^2\mid s,t>0\}\cup\{(0,0)\}$. Now, is this condition necessary?

Comment: If you only consider $f$ on the set $(0,\infty)^2 \cup \{0\}$, then the second condition is certainly necessary. For the third one, the question is: Do you want $\Vert \cdot \Vert_3$ to be a norm for **all** possible choice of norms $\Vert\cdot \Vert_1, \Vert\cdot\Vert_2$, or do you fix specific norms $\Vert\cdot\Vert_1, \Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ and want to know if $f$ has to satisfy your three properties if $\Vert\cdot\Vert_3$ is a norm? In the second case, $\Vert\cdot\Vert_1 = \Vert\cdot\Vert_2$ will yield counterexample, since you can even have $f(x,y) < 0$ for $x\neq y$.

Comment: @PhoemueX this is a good point, thank you. So my intention was to ask: what is the weakest condition to ensure that $f(\|x\|_1,\|x\|_2)$ is a norm for every norms $\|x\|_1,\|x\|_2$ on $X$. I'll edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditions can not be weakend. We will show that each one is necessary

1. Let $\left|\cdot\right|$ be any norm on $X$ and let $x\in X\setminus\left\{ 0\right\} $.
   By rescaling, we can achieve $\left|x\right|=1$. For any $\alpha,\beta>0$,
   we have that $\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert _{1}:=\alpha\cdot\left|\cdot\right|$
   and $\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert _{2}:=\beta\cdot\left|\cdot\right|$
   are norms on $X$, so that we must have
   $$
   0<\left\Vert x\right\Vert _{3}=f\left(\left\Vert x\right\Vert _{1},\left\Vert x\right\Vert _{2}\right)=f\left(\alpha\left|x\right|,\beta\left|x\right|\right)=f\left(\alpha,\beta\right).
   $$
   By choosing $\alpha,\beta$ accordingly, we see $f\left(t,s\right)>0$
   for all $t,s>0$. Clearly, we must have $f\left(0,0\right)=0$.
2. With the same choices as above, we get
   $$
   \lambda\cdot f\left(\alpha,\beta\right)=\lambda\cdot f\left(\alpha\left|x\right|,\beta\left|x\right|\right)=\lambda\left\Vert x\right\Vert _{3}=\left\Vert \lambda x\right\Vert _{3}=f\left(\left\Vert \lambda x\right\Vert _{1},\left\Vert \lambda x\right\Vert _{2}\right)=f\left(\lambda\alpha\left|x\right|,\lambda\beta\left|x\right|\right)=f\left(\lambda\left(\alpha,\beta\right)\right).
   $$
   Again, we can choose $\alpha,\beta>0$ suitably to get $\lambda\cdot f\left(s,t\right)=f\left(\lambda\left(s,t\right)\right)$
   for all $s,t>0$ and $\lambda>0$.
3. Here, we will assume $\dim\left(X\right)\geq2$ (otherwise this
   condition is probably not necessary). Hence, there are linearly independent
   $x,y$. Extend $\left(x,y\right)$ to a basis $\left(x,y,z_{1},\dots,z_{k}\right)$
   of $X$ and define the norms $\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert _{1},\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert _{2}$
   by
   \begin{eqnarray*}
   \left\Vert \left(x,y,z_{1},\dots,z_{k}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}v_{1}\\
   v_{2}\\
   \vdots\\
   v_{k+2}
   \end{matrix}\right)\right\Vert _{1} & := & \alpha_{1}\left|v_{1}\right|+\beta_{1}\left|v_{2}\right|+\left|v_{3}\right|+\dots+\left|v_{k+2}\right|,\\
   \left\Vert \left(x,y,z_{1},\dots,z_{k}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}v_{1}\\
   v_{2}\\
   \vdots\\
   v_{k+2}
   \end{matrix}\right)\right\Vert _{2} & := & \alpha_{2}\left|v_{1}\right|+\beta_{2}\left|v_{2}\right|+\left|v_{3}\right|+\dots+\left|v_{k+2}\right|,
   \end{eqnarray*}
   for arbitrary $\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},\beta_{1},\beta_{2}>0$. Here,
   we get
   \begin{eqnarray*}
   f\left(\left(\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2}\right)+\left(\beta_{1},\beta_{2}\right)\right) & = & f\left(\alpha_{1}+\beta_{1},\alpha_{2}+\beta_{2}\right)\\
    & = & f\left(\left\Vert x+y\right\Vert _{1},\left\Vert x+y\right\Vert _{2}\right)\\
    & = & \left\Vert x+y\right\Vert _{3}\\
    & \leq & \left\Vert x\right\Vert _{3}+\left\Vert y\right\Vert _{3}\\
    & = & f\left(\left\Vert x\right\Vert _{1},\left\Vert x\right\Vert _{2}\right)+f\left(\left\Vert y\right\Vert _{1},\left\Vert y\right\Vert _{2}\right)\\
    & = & f\left(\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2}\right)+f\left(\beta_{1},\beta_{2}\right),
   \end{eqnarray*}
   which is the desired estimate.

Comment: Conclusion: $f$ must be a norm! Thank you for this nicely detailed answer :).

Comment: @idm: Just one minor point: $f$ is not really a norm, since its domain of definition is not a vector space. Other than that, the properties are of course the same.